# Add elements in ArrayList from user Input

Tags: java, arraylist

For practice I'm trying to create an list of limited size.

Secondly, if size of an List is 5, then user will enter from console 5 different values one by one and once its reached 5 or entered all values, List will be showed up.

I have written some

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class Firstlastarray {

    public static List<Integer> Makearray(int arry) {

        List<Integer> mylist = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        mylist.add(arry);

        return mylist;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner ip = new Scanner(System.in);
        int ArrayElements = ip.nextInt();
        System.out.println(Makearray(ArrayElements));

    }

}
```

I know where is the problem, Like Am giving an input from user but in code its no where written that how to keep taking from input from user till the max size of List and once reached to Max size...show the List with all elements user entered.

For example, If size is 5,
Then user will enter values from console one by one lets say

```
1
2
8
9
3
```

Max limit reached..

Output would be `[1,2,8,9,3]`

But not getting any approach to achieve this...Any suggestions..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `for` loop for multiple inputs. Also, instead of creating `ArrayList` every time (in a method), you can create an `ArrayList` once and keep adding elements to it, e.g.:

```
List<Integer> mylist = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
for(int i=0 ; i < 5 ; i++){
    mylist.add(scanner.nextInt());
}
System.out.println(mylist);
scanner.close();
```

Comment: @Darshan...Thanks for this approach...Is that possible I could put your code in one method and call that method in main main method...? COde something like which starts from class and then one method which will perform this task and call that method in main method. I hope you get how am trying to do it..:)

Comment: Yes, absolutely. You can wrap this code into a method and `return` this list in the end, instead of printing it.

Answer (score 0):

Hello this is a small piece of code i did , hope it will help see other way of doing it

```
public class ArrayLimitedInput {

static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> mylist = new ArrayList<>();
    int size;
    System.out.println("Please enter size of list");
    size=scanner.nextInt();
    makeArray(mylist, size);

}

public static void makeArray(List<String> list, int size){

    for(int i=0 ; i < size ; i++){
        System.out.println("Please enter interger N° "+ (1+i));
        if(i<(size-1))
            list.add(scanner.nextInt()+ ",");
        else
            list.add(scanner.nextInt()+ "");
    }

    System.out.println("resume of enter element1s ");
    System.out.print("[");
    Iterator<String> itr = list.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        System.out.print(itr.next());
    }
    System.out.print("]");
    list.clear();
}
```

}